# Checkmarx reports Vulnerability - 'Unencrypted Web Config File' even when the code doesn't have any sensitive data

Tags: checkmarx

My code contains a web.config file without any sections for connectionStrings or any other sensitive information.

But Checkmarx SAST code scan reports "Unencrypted Web Config File" vulnerability.
"***The web.config file src/web.config does not encrypt the sensitive element found at line 1. This information can be plainly read by anyone with local file-system access.***"

Here is my web.config for reference -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url=".*" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{URL}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{URL}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
                    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <verbs>
                        <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
                    </verbs>
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
        <system.web>
            <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Vulnerability is pointed out on line 1:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

There is no sensitive sections that can be encrypted.

What is the best way to mitigate such Checkmarx vulnerability report?

Comment: do you have more than one web.config in your solution/project? if yes, are you sure this is the web.config file that Checkmarx is pointing at?

Comment: There is only one web.config. Checkmarx is pointing to the same.

Comment: @YogeshPatel Were you able to resolve this issue? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @RakeshGupta, 
For us, Checkmarx team was not ready to make any configuration change for Checkmarx, so we had to mark this vulnerality as "not exploitale" through Checkmarx GUI. Now automated scans (using Checkmarx APIs) does not count this as a vulnerability.